# SQL Server LEFT binary equals wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, binary, hex

I'm trying to understand what is going on with the following LEFT equality check.

```
select
CASE
    when LEFT(0x000012CA,4) = cast(4842 as varbinary(4))  then 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

Result: 1

Expected: 0

This should come out as `0` but will return `1`. If I change `0x000012CA` to any other value (but `0x000012EA` which is 4842) the result correctly resolves to `0`.

It appears that I can do

```
cast(LEFT(0x000012CA,4) as varbinary(4))
```

And it resolves properly, but that doesn't explain why say switching 4842 for 4841 works or `0x000012CA` to `0x000012BA`

Comment: This is a kind of weird case but the reasoning is rather simple: LEFT is converting it to a char of length 4 by converting each byte of the binary to a character. 00 is nothing, 00 is nothing, 12 is a control character and CA is Ê. EA is ê, which in certain collations is equal to Ê. Note: One way of getting rid of this is to use a different collation (e.g. `LEFT(0x000012CA, 4) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2`)

Comment: Oh, and obviously because you're doing a comparison of varchar to varbinary, the cast(4842 as varbinary(4)) is being coalesced to varchar (because of data type precedence), so you're essentially comparing Ê to ê

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand, at least why it's equaling true. Would changing it to `cast(LEFT(0x000012CA,4) as varbinary(4)) = cast(4842 as varbinary(4))` eventually hit a similar issue? Or would the LEFT to CAST help resolve it?

Comment: The issue with the original query is as I stated: it's converting both to varchar and comparing the varchar results. If comparing varbinary (which you will be doing if you cast the LEFT as varbinary(4)), you will not run into the issue. That said, I don't understand why you would be using LEFT like that, because 0x000012CA is already 4 bytes so CAST(LEFT(..., 4) AS VARBINARY(4)) seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks again, this was a snippet of code to simplify what it is really doing. The objective is to see if two varbinaries first X bytes are equal.

Comment: In that case, converting it to VARBINARY(4) without the LEFT will cull off everything but the first 4 bytes. e.g. `SELECT CAST(0x000012CAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF AS VARBINARY(4))` will result in 0x000012CA

Comment: I need `VARBINARY(4)` to actually be `VARBINARY(X * Y)` as it's variable based on certain inputs, it doesn't look like SQL supports that type of assignment though.

Answer (score 0):

Try an excessively larger number to see if it works.

```
select
CASE
    when LEFT(0x000012CA,4) = cast(4842 as varbinary(400))  then 1
    ELSE 0
END
```